# Insert string in SQL Server column based on length of existing text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 table and a specific column `Title` which contains a mixture of strings that all start with 'WM' and end in a store number, for example  `WM24` or `WM1234`.

What I'd like to do is normalize all the rows to a standard format of `WMXXXX`' (where `XXXX` is a 4-digit store number). So `WM26` would become `WM0026` and `WM123` would become `WM0123`, but `WM1234` is unaffected.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING(Title, 3, LEN(Title) - 2)` or `RIGHT(Title, Len(Title)-2))` or `Replace(Title, 'WM', '')` to pull off the numbers from the `WM`. Then pad it out with zeros.

Here it is with the `Substring()`:

```
SELECT 'WM' + Right('0000' + Substring(Title, 3, LEN(Title) - 2), 4) as title
FROM yourtable;
```

Or `Right()`:

```
SELECT 'WM' + Right('0000' + RIGHT(Title, Len(Title)-2)), 4) as title
FROM yourtable;
```

Or `Replace()`:

```
SELECT 'WM' + Right('0000' + Replace(Title, 'WM', '')), 4) as title
FROM yourtable;
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure this is pretty simple. But I have to ask, if every single row starts with "WM" why bother? That is incredibly redundant. Start by removing that prefix then make a 4 character string of what is left.

```
select 'WM' + right('0000' + substring(YourColumn, 3, len(YourColumn)), 4)
from YourTable
```

Comment: the WM is used to filter from other customers that might have the same store number, and the 4-digit number is for standardization with respect to reports, etc.